# auto-timed Outlook Journal Entry from .bat file

Tags: batch-file, timer, outlook, journal

I am hoping someone can help... I have a .bat file which creates a new Journal Entry in MS Outlook (2007)(OS is Win7Pro). This batch file auto-populates the subject line, date and start time lines. It also auto-starts the timer function, so I can track how long service calls take me. However, the timer does not auto-start when the .bat file is being run from other machines.

.bat file content below:

```
START /d "%Program Files%\Microsoft Office\Office12\" outlook.exe /c ipm.activity.SupportJournal1 /m "&subject=2nd Shift Call&Companies=LSA&starttime=%date%%time%&body=program - problem - operator - programmer "
```

I have also designed a custom form, which is the basic journal entry, with the addition of a small line of script attached to the form, to start the timer, as I have not figured how to do this with the .bat file.

```
Function Item_Open()
    If Item.Size = 0 Then     ' it's a new entry
        Item.Start = Now
        Item.StartTimer
    End If 
End Function
```

My end goal is to run the .bat when the phone rings, enter who called and what the problem, have the timer running, and timer end when the journal is saved. Multiple users possible, all saving to a shared journal.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I could use something similar.

Comment: sadly i was unable to find a way to do this. I ended up finding a different way to reach my goal.